# Infinite Loop passing parameters to screen and setting parameters to usestate constant

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a react native project. I am trying to pass in a variable object as a parameter between screens. I have it so that if the screen that has the passed in params senses that a parameter was detected, I want it to set the param object as the value of a useState constant.

I pass in the parameter using navigation.navigate like this:

```
    const newFilter = {
      home_type:selectedHomeTypes,
      minPrice: min,
      maxPrice: max,
      bathsMin: bathCount,
      bedsMin: bedCount,
      sqftMin: sqftMin,
      sqftMax: sqftMax,
    }
    navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {newFilter: newFilter})
```

I have an if statement in the `HomeScreen` that is supposed to detect if there is a `route.params?.newFilter`

It is sensing it and console logging the correct information in the function. The issue is that when it runs `updateAppliedFilter()` and then `setAppliedFilter()` I get an error that is an infinite loop issue.

Error:

```
Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

childScreen:

```
const applyFilters = () => {
    const newFilter = {
      home_type:selectedHomeTypes,
      minPrice: min,
      maxPrice: max,
      bathsMin: bathCount,
      bedsMin: bedCount,
      sqftMin: sqftMin,
      sqftMax: sqftMax,
    }
    navigation.navigate('HomeScreen', {newFilter: newFilter})
  }
```

ParentScreen:

```
  const updateAppliedFilter = (filter) => {
    setAppliedFilters(filter)
  }

  if(route.params?.newFilter){
    console.log('filterFound')
    console.log(route.params.newFilter)
    updateAppliedFilter(route.params.newFilter)
  }
```

When i do not run the `setAppliedFilter` it works correctly and renders the `console.logs` 1 time. When I add the `setAppliedFilter`, it goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: What is `setAppliedFilters` and where is it declared? Where is the code in the last snippet being run? Please edit your post to include a more complete [mcve] so we've better context what the code is doing *and when* it's doing it. If I had to hazard a guess this code is running as an unintentional side-effect, and I'm sure there's more to the error message that likely informs you of a possible fix.

Comment: Because of every state changes render your code and execute your if block and it goes to infinite loop. Your shared ParentScreen code should be in useeffect hook. It has route.params.newFilter as a dependency. So that when route.params.newFilter is changed, useEffect will execute only one times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you navigate to `ParentScreen` and provide `newFilter` via the `route.params`, then `updateAppliedFilter` will be called inside the `ParentScreen` and trigger a state change via `setAppliedFilters` which will eventually rerender the screen. However, the `route.params` do not change during this rerender (they will never be set to undefined), thus the `updateAppliedFilter` function will be called again and again.

You can guard this using a `useEffect`.

**ParentScreen**

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (route.params?.newFilter) {
        updateAppliedFilter(route.params.newFilter);
    }
}, [route.params])
```